# How to write a stream of strings into a MS word file through matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, file, docx, doc

After generating a lengthy string through matlab, how to write it as MS office files (doc,docx) in matlab?

Comment: You are basically asking for a external library. There are plenty possibilities available. Keep in mind that MATLAB supports calling Python, Java and .NET libraries. For each of these technologies there exists at least one possibilities to write word documents.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. now i have a clear idea about how to do that. your answer is the seed of my tree :) @daniel

Answer (score 0):

http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3149-save2word

please go through above link
use save2word function
of fprintf function

Comment: Please also add some content from the link.